# Simplify Applescript with Repeat

Tags: applescript, repeat

I wrote this little AppleScript to assign value 11 to 3 different variable but something doesn't work and the final value is alway 0 ... I want to simplyfy a loop of IF from my main Applescript with just a couple of Repeat ...

Here my code:

```
set compteur to 1
set test_01 to 0
set test_02 to 0
set test_03 to 0

repeat while compteur < 4
    
    set valeur_de_fou to ("set test_0" & (compteur as text) & " to 11")
    run script valeur_de_fou
    display dialog (compteur as text) & " - " & test_01 & " - " & test_02 & " - " & test_03
    set compteur to compteur + 1
    
end repeat
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for not using a list?  Note that the scripts you run with `run script`are independent and separate from the main script.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it with a list

Answer (score 1):

When you use the command `run script "set test_01 to 11"`, it will do just that, but what is being run is a separate script - the variable `test_01` in *that* script is completely different from the `test_01` in *your* script.  You can manipulate strings and set parameters to dynamically create a script for for `run script` to get a result, but it will still be a separate script.

AppleScript does not have any provisions for dynamically using identifiers; variable identifiers are set when a script is compiled.  Instead of using a bunch of separate variables like `test_01`, `test_02`, and `test_3`, the normal approach would be to create a *list* (an ordered, integer-indexed collection of objects), e.g. `set test to {0, 0, 0}`.  The list items can then be accessed by using their position (index), e.g. `item 1 of test`.

Using your script as a template, an example would be something like:

```
set test to {0, 0, 0}
repeat with indx from 1 to (count test) -- repeat with loopVariable (from startValue to stopValue)
   set (item indx of test) to 11 -- set
   display dialog (indx as text) & " - " & item 1 of test & " - " & item 2 of test & " - " & item 3 of test -- get
end repeat
return test
```

Comment: Finally a clear answer :) thank you so much